# No query registered for [...]

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

POST: {{HOST}}/_search
ElasticSearch returns me "No query registered for [parental_rating]" error when trying to look up entries using the following query.
I am using 5.5.1 ES version

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter" : {
                "parental_rating" : {
                    "lte": 6
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the example how it looks the data: Here is the example how it looks the data:

```
{
  "took": 14,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 128,
    "successful": 128,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 182310,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "gracenote_1528767603035",
        "_type": "program",
        "_id": "3a0cf999-bfd0-4195-a8e4-ccaaf1b5d4d3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "imported_at": "Tue Jun 12 2018 00:21:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
          "type": "program",
          "title": "Rusty rockt!; Die Luftrettung",
          "description": "Ruby nimmt an einemsen Rustyommen.",
          "summary": "Ruby nimmt an einem TalRusty und den Bits.",
          "short_summary": null,
          "season_no": 1,
          "episode_no": 8,
          "season_id": "13005345",
          "id": "91984",
          "series_id": "13000950",
          "people": [
            {
              "name": "Kyle Breitkopf",
              "character": "Rusty",
              "role": "Voice",
              "id": "682794"
            }
          ],
          "genres": [
            "78",
            "11",
            "2",
            "99",
            "44"
          ],
          "parental_rating": 12,
```

Comment: Please post the sample document

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a `range` query here. The correct query should look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter" : {
                "range": {
                    "parental_rating" : {
                        "lte": 6
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .hmm not work good, I still get other parental ratings :(
for example:  "parental_rating": 12,

Comment: How do you send your query?

Comment: in Body with POST (JSON)

Comment: Ok then I suspect that you `parental_rating` field has been mapped as a string. Can you show what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?

Comment: yes that was the problem, in the schemas file the parental_rating type was text, and now I replaced with "long" type.